# Ionic ion-nav-view misses the animations

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I looked at [this documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) and at [this example](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz) but I'm not able to get the smooth slide-in transition of the new page content (currently when I press my button the page blinks and loads in the new content, without the animation as visible in the example).

What am I doing wrong?

My `index.html` looks like that

```
<ion-pane>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
            <h1 class="title">Ionic Test</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-nav-view>
            <ion-content padding="true">
                ...
            </ion-content>
            <ion-footer-bar>
                <button class="bar bar-footer bar-calm button-large" ui-sref="quiz">
                    <p class="title">Start the quiz<p>
                </button>
            </ion-footer-bar>
        </ion-nav-view>
    </ion-pane>
```

The `app.js` looks like that

```
var quizApp = angular.module('quizApp', ['ionic']);

quizApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});

quizApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('quiz', {
        url: '/quiz',
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: "templates/quiz.html",
                controller: "quizController as quizCtrl"
            }
        }
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});

quizApp.controller('quizController', ['$ionicPlatform', '$http', function($ionicPlatform, $http) {
    this.blub = "test";
    this.test = function(text) {
        alert(text);
    }
}]);
```

And the `quiz.html` looks like that

```
<ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <h2 style="font-size:50px;">{{quizCtrl.blub}}</h2>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it. The only problem was that I declared `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");` but didn't defined a `state` for `/`. This missing `state` crashed the whole application but didn't threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using something like:

```
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```